# Compile inside a controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

The problem occurs as follows,

```
            $scope.name = "Maximilian";
            var template = "<div><span>{{name}}</span></div>";
            var content = $compile(template)($scope);
            console.info(content);  //shows compiled innerText
            $scope.outputContainer = content[0].innerText; // shows uncompiled Content
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What does the error say? Did you inject `$compile` into your controller?

Comment: i get uncompiled Content .. it is mentioned in the comments of the code example.

Comment: [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLenjedL/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to put it into a 0 second $timeout-function.
If there is a better one let me know.

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.outputContainer = content[0].innerHTML;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cLenjedL/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for an evaluated content.

your controller could look like this.

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Maximilian";
    var template = "<div><span>"+$scope.$eval("name")+"</span></div>";
    $scope.outputContainer = template;
}
```

Personally I would create a directive and use the transclude function for the html snippet.

I have updated your [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLenjedL/11/)